# Validating two inputs in CKEditor dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've gotten the custom validator to work on each field, but they should be mututally exclusive: how to validate one field against the other?

URL: [input1]
OR
Keyword: [input2]

And I can validate either one with:

```
setup: function() {...},
validate: CKEditor.dialog.validate.functions(function(val) {
  var input1 = val; // value of THIS input field
  var input2 = ???; // value of the other input field?)
  return (input1 == "" || input2 == "");
},"Error message here"),
commit: function() {...}
```

Simplified example, but you can see what I need.  A pointer to the other field from inside the validator.

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to do the trick...

```
validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.functions(function(val)) {
  var input1 = val,
      input2 = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement('tabID','input-2').getValue()
  return ((input1=="" && input2=="") || (input1!="" && input2!=""));
}, "one or the other [but not both!] is required");
```